# HAProxy in front of Varnish not setting X-FORWARDED-FOR

Tags: haproxy, varnish, x-forwarded-for

Until the last few days we had the following architecture:
HAProxy -> 2 Backend servers

Now we have:
HAProxy -> Varnish -> 2 Backend servers

Before, HAProxy was setting the "X-FORWARDED-FOR" header correctly every time. Now however, it only sets the header *sometimes*.

By *sometimes* I mean: I make a request to a PHP script that prints the contents of $_SERVER (holds the header in discussion).

No matter how many times I make the request, HAProxy won't set the header. IF however, I make a request to my script, and then quickly (before the request ends) I hit refresh (so basically I'm making 2 simultaneous requests), the header is being set.

Did someone stumble upon this very weird issue and can point me in the right direction?

Note: putting varnish in front of HAProxy is not an option.

Comment: What's the HAProxy configuration look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you forgot to use "option http-server-close" in your haproxy configuration. It was OK earlier because your backend servers did not enable keep-alive by default.